# Push object keys and its values to array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like this:

```
{
 "id": 23,
 "name": "Jacob",
 "link": {
     "rel": "self",
     "link": "www.abc.com"
 },
 "company":{
       "data":{
           "id": 1,
           "ref": 324
       }
 }
```

I want to store each key with its value to an array in javascript or typescript like this
[["id":23], ["name":"Jacob"], ["link":{......, ......}]] and so on

I am doing this so that I can append an ID for each.
My best guess I would loop through the array and append an ID/a flag for each element, which I don't know how to do as well.... how to address this issue ? thanks

Comment: What you want is invalid syntax. Instead, explain what problem you're solving.

Comment: Yes. How about something like that: [["id",23], ["name","Jacob"], ["link",{......, ......}]]

Comment: hmm I see... its a bit complicated to explain, let me get back to you later

Comment: @MauricePerry Yes , thats what i want

Comment: answered and added demo

Comment: What is the problem you want to solve? What do you want to be able to do after creating these arrays?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var arr = [];

for (var prop in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      var innerObj = {};
      innerObj[prop] = obj[prop];
      arr.push(innerObj)
   }
}
    
console.log(arr);
```

here is demo https://plnkr.co/edit/9PxisCVrhxlurHJYyeIB?p=preview

Comment: thats close man, thanx but still it separates the keys in an array and values in a different one `array[2] -> 0: id  1: 23`

Comment: it is just displaying like that it is actually  ["id", 23]

Comment: Arrays in JS has indexes. so if you want to reach "id" you just console.log(arr[0][0]) to see it

Comment: console.log(arr[0]);  the result is ["id", 23]

Comment: @Sahil I dont need it to be separated... I am using ionic 2 and to refer to values I reference the keys only in order to get them

Answer (score 5):

```
p.forEach( function (country) { 
  country.forEach( function (entry) {
    entry.push( {"value" : 'Greece', "synonyms" : 'GR'});
   });
 });
```

Comment: Hello, an explanation of the code would help other users.

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use experimental [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let obj = {
 "id": 23,
 "name": "Jacob",
 "link": {
     "rel": "self",
     "link": "www.abc.com"
 },
 "company":{
       "data":{
           "id": 1,
           "ref": 324
       }
 }};

console.log(Object.entries(obj).map(item => ({[item[0]]:item[1]})));
```

for unsupported browsers you can use polyfill: https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries

Comment: thats not what Im looking for...it separates the values "id",23

Comment: I added `Array.map` function to my code, please check again if it is your desired result

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Object.keys` method to get an array of the keys, then use the `Array#map` method to return a new array containing individual objects for each property.

This ES6 one-liner should do it:

```
const splitObject = o => Object.keys(o).map(e => ({ [e]: o[e] }));
```

Or in ES5:

```
function splitObject(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).map(function(e) {
        return Object.defineProperty({}, e, { 
            value: o[e], 
            enumerable: true 
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an iterative/recursive approach with the object and their nested parts. It works for any depths.

```js
function getKeyValue(object) {
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(function (result, key) {
        return result.concat(
            object[key] && typeof object[key] === 'object' ?
            getKeyValue(object[key]) :
            [[key, object[key]]]
        );
    }, []);
}

var data = { id: 23, name: "Jacob", link: { rel: "self", link: "www.abc.com" }, company: { data: { id: 1, ref: 324 } } };

console.log(getKeyValue(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  var res = [];
_.transform( {
  "id": 23,
  "name": "Jacob",
  "link": {
    "rel": "self",
    "link": "www.abc.com"
  },
  "company": {
    "data": {
      "id": 1,
      "ref": 324
    }
  }
}, function(result, value, key) {
    res.push(key +':'+value);
}, {});
```

You can use underscore

Answer (score 0):

**Supported in all major browser, including IE11**

Object.entries() gives you exactly this.

```
const obj = {
  id: 23,
  name: 'Jacob',
  link: {
    rel: 'self',
    link: 'www.abc.com'
  },
  company: {
    data: {
      id: 1,
      ref: 324
    }
   }
 };

Object.entries(obj);
// output:
[
    [
        "id",
        23
    ],
    [
        "name",
        "Jacob"
    ],
    [
        "link",
        {
            "rel": "self",
            "link": "www.abc.com"
        }
    ],
    [
        "company",
        {
            "data": {
                "id": 1,
                "ref": 324
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=[{"Name":ABC,"Count":123},{"Name":XYZ,"Count":456}];
var arr = [];

for (var prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var innerObj = {};
        innerObj[0] = obj[prop];
        arr.push(innerObj[0]);
      }
    }
```

/* Here above exmple innerobj index set to 0 then we will get same data into arr if u not menstion then arr will conatins arr[0] our result.
    then we need to call first record obj arr[0][0] like this*/

Answer (score 0):

```
const foo = { "bar": "foobar", "foo": "foobar" }
Object.entries(foo)
```

should result in:

```
[["bar", "foobar"], ["foo", "foobar"]]
```

maybe there's a function to pass to convert all commas to colons

Here's the documentation
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries